# Adding More Than One @EnvironmentObject to NavigationView

Tags: swiftui

How does one add more than 1 EnvironmentObject to a NavigationView. So I have 2 EnvironmentObjects that are really basic, this is how they look like.

```
class NavigationEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isShowingChildView: Bool = false
}

class FullNameEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstName = ""
    @Published var middleName = ""
    @Published var lastName = ""
}
```

I have 3 views, view 1 is the first name & also the root view, view 2 is the middle name & view 3 is the last name. Now this is how I added my EnvironmentObjects to my root view of my navigation.

```
struct RootView: View {
    let firstName = "Jane"
    @StateObject var navigationEO = NavigationEnvironmentObject()
    @StateObject var fullNameEO = FullNameEnvironmentObject()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text(firstName)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                    NavigationLink(isActive: $navigationEO.isShowingChildView, destination: { ChildView1() }) {
                        Button {
                            fullNameEO.firstName = firstName
                            navigationEO.isShowingChildView = true
                        } label: {
                            Text("Middle Name Screen")
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                                .background(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationTitle("First Name")
        }
        .environmentObject(navigationEO)
        .environmentObject(fullNameEO)
    }
}
```

Okay so here is the problem that I'm facing right now. When I add my 2 EnvironmentObject in the NavigationView like above it's giving me a weird behavior. So when I click the the middle name screen button from rootView it takes me to ChildView1. Now when I click the last name screen button from ChildView1 it goes to ChildView2 but instantly goes back to ChildView1. I don't know why this is happening.

Here is how my other 2 views look like so it can be easily replicated.

```
struct ChildView1: View {
    let middleName = "Unknown"
    @EnvironmentObject var fullNameEO: FullNameEnvironmentObject
    @State var isShowingChildView2: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text(middleName)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            
                NavigationLink(isActive: $isShowingChildView2, destination: { ChildView2() }) {
                    Button {
                        fullNameEO.middleName = middleName
                        isShowingChildView2 = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Last Name Screen")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                            .background(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
                .isDetailLink(false)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationTitle("Middle Name")
    }
}


struct ChildView2: View {
    let lastName = "Doe"
    @EnvironmentObject var fullNameEO: FullNameEnvironmentObject
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationEO: NavigationEnvironmentObject
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text(lastName)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Button {
                    fullNameEO.lastName = lastName
                    navigationEO.isShowingChildView = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Pop to root view")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.purple)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                        .background(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationTitle("Last Name")
    }
}
```

Want to know why this is happening. Would appreciate any help

Comment: @Asperi trying to get use to it. It's the only way I know how to do some validation, example check if a user exist in my database. Unless there is a better way without using a button?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured out a way to do it. All I had to do is add isDetailLink modifier to my navigation link in my RootView.

```
NavigationLink(isActive: $navigationEO.isShowingChildView, destination: { ChildView1() }) {
    Button {
        navigationEO.isShowingChildView = true
        fullNameEO.firstName = firstName
    } label: {
        Text("Middle Name Screen")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
.isDetailLink(false)
```

Don't really know what this does but it works, hopefully this helps someone out there having the same problem as me.